# reading azure pipeline environment variables in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-pipelines

I have set environment variable in azure yaml pipeline like this

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |      $env:MY_VARIABLE = "$(my-value)"
$env:MY_VARIABLE >> test.txt
...
```

when I run the pipeline and go to published artifact in summary section of the pipeline, I can see that test.txt has correct value. Is there a way I can read  this `MY_VARIABLE` in c# code, which is going to be run with a specflow task in this yaml pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that by using `env:` in task like below we can have compiled C# code ( in my case running on ms hosted agent)  read the variables directly.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: tests
  env:
    MY_VARIABLE = "$(my-value)"
```

and then in c# code we can do like this

```
 string  var= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_VARIABLE", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Note that without using `env:` , it may not work

Answer (score 1):

You can't read Azure Pipelines variable directly in C#. However, each Azure Pipeline variable is mapped to an environment variable (except for secrets). You can read about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables).

So, all that you need is `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`.

And of course you need to run your code on pipeline, not compile create package and then run somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way , I can read the variable inside my specflow tests ? These tests will run on a vm/container .

Comment: If you want to run them on the build agent on a docker container you need to pass [them](https://vsupalov.com/docker-environment-variables-from-host/).

Answer (score 0):

```
string var_calling = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variable_name_same_as_yml_file,EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?